# TcpClient ReceiveTimeout и SendTimeout в C#

Tags: c#, qtcpsocket, tcpclient, tcplistener

Пишу TCP листенер наткнулся на такие вот свойства в TCPClient `ReceiveTimeout` и `SendTimeout`.

Есть несколько вопросов

1. `ReceiveTimeout` ждет подключения указанное количество времени, но не совсем понятно, например если он ждет подключения 5 мин, но происходит подключение и отправляется ответ в течении 10 сек - этот клиент и дальше будет висеть 4:50 сек ? Из-за блокировки Read
2. Роли `SendTimeOut` не понял вообще в контексте листенера, можно ли ссылки, или как-то объяснить его роль ?

Вот мой код:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_listeningUrl), _liteningPort);
                listener.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    client.ReceiveTimeout = 540000;
                    client.SendTimeout = 540000;
                    client.NoDelay = true;

                    new Thread(()=>
                    {
                        ThreadProc(client);
                        client.Close();
                    }).Start();
                }
```

Суть кода в том, что при поступлении запроса на листенер идет очень долгая работа в БД, иногда 3 мин. Мне показалось, что подключенный клиент просто отваливается недождавшись

Comment: В цикле `while(true)` у вас бесконечно создаются и запускаются новые потоки - выглядит странно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А как вы ещё хотите, чтобы выглядел многопоточный сервер? Он ожидает нового соединения и помещает его в обработку в отдельный поток.

Answer (score 2):

`ReceiveTimeout` позволяет задать время, которое ваш сокет будет ждать входящих данных. Если за указанное время данные так и не поступили, считается, что удалённый клиент не ответил. Если вы хотите ожидать данные неограниченный временной промежуток, установите `ReceiveTimeout` в -1 (аналогично работает и для `SendTimeout`).

`SendTimeout` позволяет задать время, за которое данные, переданные на сокет, должны быть отправлены удалённому клиенту. Если данные так и не были отправлены за это время, они уже никогда не будут отправлены.

> Суть кода в том, что при поступлении запроса на листенер идет очень долгая работа в БД, иногда 3 мин. Мне показалось, что подключенный клиент просто отваливается недождавшись

Скорее всего так и есть. Сокет удалённого клиента не хочет ждать ответа 3 минуты и закрывает соединение. Нужно исправить код клиента, добавив в него установку свойства `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` в -1, ну или там на 5*60*1000 мс (по крайней мере перед чтением ответа вашего сервера).

---

Ну так же могу порекомендовать использовать `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` вместо `Thread.Start()` :)

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ваш ответ! А если `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` установить просто в ноль, или не использовать (по умолчанию ноль)?

Comment: Я думаю вылетит `IOException` на чтении.